# How is our physical body made of Panchabhutas?

Tags: philosophy

Indian Philosophy says Panchabhutas make composition of our body. Panchabhutas are Earth Water Air Fire Sky. How can they make our physical body? Isn't our Physical Body made of cells as science proves?

Comment: Well, by fire they don't mean the literal fire, they mean plasma, by water(even if you take it literally it is correct) they mean liquid(all) by air(vayu) they mean gas. And by sky(akash) they mean space.

Comment: the material elements are composed of different combinations of the fine elements. The fine elements (and their combinations into the material elements) are defined in the vedas. Don't take literally the translations of the fine elements earth, fire, water, etc. literally. This is a duplicate question.. Please try a search on this blog..

Comment: Outer body sheath is made of Earth(prithvi) and can be held and is solid, inside body Water(jal) is flowing in the form of blood, but the blood is heated and red because of Agni(fire) of Atman and hence body feels warm when touched, the circulation need Vayu(air) or prana through nostrils and into core heart, the whole process is happening in the Akasha(Space). Body cells also need circulated blood by 5 elements to survive, after death body becomes cold blue and decomposes because Atman(Soul) and its agni/heat is missing inside body to heat up and circulate blood and metabolism stops.

Comment: Just like your computer or phone need battery cell or electricity to charge and work and feels warm or hot when touched, similarly any living body need soul, a type of heat(agni), to perform metabolism without which any body turns dead, blue and cold.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one views the world from the eyes of science, then our body is made up of cells and is an large chemical vessel. The *Panch-Maha-Bhootas* are those five elements from which not just the body but also the universe is made of. Separating that layer of science, which describes the body on cellular levels, the body is said to have 25 '*Gunas*' which can be grouped into each of those five *Tattvas*.

From the ***Gyaan-Sankuli Tantra*** which is said to be the part of the lost ***Shambhavi Tantra***:

> उमा प्रृच्छति हे देव ! पिण्डब्रह्माण्डलक्षणम्‌ ।
> पञ्चभूतं कथं देव गुणा: के पच्चविद्यति: ॥
>
> > Devi Asks, O Deva what are the symptoms (*Lakshanam* or one may call it properties) of this *Brahmanda-PanchBhootas* of the body ? How are those 25 *Gunas*?

> **ईश्वर उवाच--**
> अस्थि मांसं नखञ्चैव त्वग्लोमणि च पञ्चमम्‌ ।
> पृथ्वीपञ्चगुणाः प्रोक्ता ब्रह्मज्ञानेन भाषते ॥२०॥
>
> > Deva says: *Asthi* (bones), *Masa* (muscles), *Tvacha* (skin) *Nakha* (Nails), *Rome* (hair) are of *'PruthviTattva'*.

> शुक्रशोणितमज्जा च मलमूत्रञ्च पञ्चमम ।
> अपां प्रञ्चगुणा: प्रोक्ता ब्रह्मज्ञानेन भाषते ॥२१॥
>
> > *Shukra* (Venus-Semen), *ShoShit* (शोषीत ?), *Majja* (Marrow), *Mala* (waste), *Mutra* (Urine) are of *JalaTattava*.

> निद्राक्षुधातृषा चैव क्लान्तिरालस्यं पञ्चमम्‌ |
> तेज: पञ्चगुणा: प्रोक्ता ब्रह्मज्ञानेंन भाषते ॥२२॥
>
> > *Nidra* (Sleep), *Ksudha* (Hunger), *Trushna* (Thurst) and *kranti* (Growth) And *Alasya* (Lazyness) are of *'TejoTattava'*.

> घारणं चालनं क्षेपं सङ्कोचं प्रसरस्तथा।
> वायो: पञ्चगुणाः प्रोक्ता ब्रह्मज्ञानेन भाषते ॥२३॥
>
> > *Dharan* (intake), *Chalan* (to walk- Proceed), *Kshepan* ( to launch), *Sankochan* (Hesitation), *Prasaran* (to Express) are of *VayuTattva*.

> कामं क्रोधं तथा मोहं लंज्जा लोभञ्च पंञ्चमम्‌।
> नभ: पञ्चगुणा: प्रोक्ता ब्रह्मज्ञानेंन भाषते ॥२४॥
>
> > *Kama* (Pleasures), *Krodha* (anger), *Lobha* ( Greed), *Moha* (attraction) and *Lajja* (Shame) are of *AakashTattva*.

**Edit:**

It is somewhat confusing to have *kama*, *Krodha* etc as space elements. The answer to this was found in **Shri Dasbodh** written by **Shri Samarth Ramdas**

In the **4-th Samasa** on **Gross PanchMahabutas** in the **8-th Chapter- of the Mayodbha (On Maya) of Shree-Dasbodha:**

> ॥ श्रीराम ॥ केवळ मूर्ख तें नेणें । म्हणौन लागलें सांगणें। पंचभूतांचीं लक्षणें । विशद करूनि ॥ १ ॥ पंचभूतांचा कर्दम जाला। आतां न वचे वेगळा केला । परंतु कांहीं येक वेगळाला। करून दावूं ॥ २॥
>
> > Who are only Fools don't get it, thus I need to describe the characteristics of the Pancha-Maha-Bhootas (Gross form) in a greater detail. (1) The PanchMahabutas now mix among each other (inside Maya), now it would not be possible to separate them (thus we can't find a Bhoota completely separate than other) . Still I will show their occurrence separately.

> वन्ही शंकराचे नेत्रींचा। वन्ही काळाचे क्षुधेचा । वन्ही परीघ भूगोलाचा। तेज बोलिजे ॥ २७॥ जें प्रकाशरूप । तें तें तेजाचें स्वरूप। शोशक उष्णादि आरोप । तेज जाणावा ॥ २८ ॥
>
> > The Agni inside the third eye of Shiva, Hunger which causes heat (it happens below the belly button near Swadishthan, the place below the sun) and the fire that revolve near earth, know it to be of Tejo tattva. Which is 'Prakash-Rupi' (light like) know it to be of Tejo tattva. The processes which cause production of heat, as well as which absorb the heat come under tejo tattva.

> आकाश तमापासून जालें। म्हणोन कामक्रोधें वोष्टिलें । अज्ञान शून्य बोलिलें । नाम तयाचें  ॥ ५५ ॥ अज्ञानें कामक्रोधादिक । मोहो भये आणी शोक । हा अज्ञानाचा विवेक । आकाशगुणें ॥५६ ॥ नास्तिक नकारवचन । तेंचि शून्याचें लक्षण । तयास म्हणती हृदयझशून्य। अज्ञान प्राणी ॥५७॥आकाश स्तब्धपणें शून्य । शून्य म्हणिजे तें अज्ञान । अज्ञान म्हणिजे कठिण । रूप तयाचें ॥५८॥
>
> > Akasha (space) has formed out of Tamo-Guna thus we include Kama and Krodha into it. Akasha is Shunya (zero) and so is Agynaan (false knowledge). (55) From the false knowledge he achieves kama, krodha, moha, fear etc. These traits like kama and krodha have formed because of the nature of Akasha. (56) Being Nastik, and doing nothing this is a quality of being Shunya. Hridya-Shunya is a person who has no emotions, such people who see the world with false knowledge, consider the qualities of being Shunya as truth.

Comment: You mean Gyana Sankalini Tantra?

Comment: @Rickross Its ज्ञानसङ्कुली. Need to confirm if Gyana Sankalini is same as Gyana Sankuli.

Comment: Yes they are same

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming.

Comment: Thankyou for the great answer sir! I have few doubts. How are /Kama (Pleasures), Krodha (anger), Lobha ( Greed), Moha (attraction) and Lajja (Shame)/ linked to Akasha?I mean what is the logic to link like that

Comment: Is Fire related to TejoTattava ? How can Sleep revolution and lazyness relate to fire

Comment: @Proxy Thanks a lot but still I amnt convinced for Space and Fire

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru look at this: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brihat-samhita/d/doc229329.html Light gives color to many things that we see, so hence it is fire. As for space, we wouldn't be able to swallow if we didn't have space in us lol.